# How to recognise user behaviour data on substrate chains? (Events + Extrinsics)

Tags: extrinsic, events, data-analytics

*Context*: Specifically trying to measure user behaviour data on substrate chains.

*Questions:*

1. Is there any specific data that indicates whether a user triggered an extrinsic or an event?
2. Do only signed extrinsics need to be checked to get user triggered transactions? Do unsigned extrinsics have any useful user transaction data?
3. Is there a unified way to identify user transactions in any module?

Answer (score 1):

Generally if the [Phase](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_system/enum.Phase.html) is ApplyExtrisic then it's user activity, but also the user can for example send an xcm message upwards to the relay chain and that will get executed in ParachainSystem set_validation_data and so those may also contain user activity (You can probably see whether it does or not by which events are associated with that extrinsic).